# Missing Terminal, Menu Bar and other things

Tags: python, 15.10, screen, gui

I have uninstalled python 3.4 and python 3.5 by mistakenly. After Reboot, I have faced that problem. I didn't reach anything like terminal, menu or another bar. Only I can open a folder and reach to folders with GUI. **How to fix that problem?** Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to get a working terminal by pressing `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` (Actually, any F-Key from 1 to 6 should work).

If you get a Terminal, you should be able to reinstall the appropriate python package via apt.

Also, it might be worth it to check first if you can fix it by installing the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage, which contains some of the vital parts of your system:
`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't remember to use Ctrl + Alt + F1. Thanks.